# locust unrecognized arguments when running as lib

Tags: locust

The following codes are from Locust examples - [use_as_lib](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/use_as_lib.py).

```py
import gevent
from locust import HttpUser, task
from locust.env import Environment
from locust.stats import stats_printer, stats_history
from locust.log import setup_logging

setup_logging("INFO", None)


class MyUser(HttpUser):
    host = "https://docs.locust.io"

    @task
    def t(self):
        self.client.get("/")


env = Environment(user_classes=[MyUser])
runner = env.create_local_runner()

web_ui = env.create_web_ui("127.0.0.1", 8089)

env.events.init.fire(environment=env, runner=runner, web_ui=web_ui)

gevent.spawn(stats_printer(env.stats))

gevent.spawn(stats_history, env.runner)

runner.start(1, spawn_rate=10)

gevent.spawn_later(60, lambda: runner.quit())

runner.greenlet.join()

web_ui.stop()
```

If I run it with `python use_as_lib.py`, everything works fine. But if I run it with `python use_as_lib.py -c argument01 -b argument02`, it will fail with:

```
use_as_lib.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -c -b argument02
```

In my case, the snippet above is part of a big program, which has its own command line arguments.

I checked a bit, seems `argument_parser.ui_extra_args_dict()` [here](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/b0baaebbcd2e7705a5c6ee298ac17799c96b02bb/locust/web.py#L529) invoked by `env.create_web_ui("127.0.0.1", 8089)` will parse all the arguments, which cause this issue.

Any ideas on how to fix it ? Thanks!

Comment: You probably want use *either* argument passing *or* as-a-library, not both.

Comment: But actually I'm running Locust as a lib in another command-line-program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parsed set of parameters when you create the environment, slightly less hack-y than your suggestion. Something like this:

```
parser = locust.argument_parser.get_parser() 
parsed_options = parser.parse_args("-f yourlocustfile.py --headless <other params>")
env = Environment(user_classes=[MyUser], parsed_options=parsed_options=parsed_options)
```

Would that work?

Comment: haven't look into the source code to understand it, but will, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround I used. So far it works. But more like a hack.

```py
# ...
tmp = sys.argv
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]
env.create_web_ui("127.0.0.1", 8089)
sys.argv = tmp
# ...
```